# PhoneGap: Scaling down a webpage with viewport

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, mobile

I am creating a quick prototype of an App we are going to be building at work so we can do a quick user test on some functionality.

My designer created my images at a 640px width to match the resolution of the iPhone 5. So to make things simple and quick I used this viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">
```

This work perfectly in mobile Safari but now that I have wrapped it in PhoneGap it is behaving like the scale is set to 1. Any thoughts on what I need to do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: The maximum scale might not have been needed, but it is in my snippet so I left it in.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found it. There is a 'config.xml' in the root of the project. Setting this line:

```
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
```

To be 'true' like my snippet here shows, made the app scale correctly like it did online.

Comment: hi i found this in staging config.xml,can you please tell where should i put this line

Answer (score 1):

just tested, preference is not complete solutioin, do following:

config.xml:
preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />

main activity, enable viewport in settings AFTER loadurl:

```
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(),1);   
    WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings(); 
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true); 
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Comment: Works, combined with this.appView.setInitialScale(50); (for .5 initial-scale) and <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" /> in config.xml

Answer (score -2):

I see above a possible mistake. Maybe my betters can comment.

1) The initial questioner seems to want to scale. The end of the line states **"user-scalable=no"**. This could result in no scaling - scaling 100%. Browsers let you scale no matter what, right? So Safari result was a red herring.
Also, the inital and maximum scale are the same.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">
```

2) According to Sebastions reply, perhaps the correct value is **"50"** not "0.5".