# Phonegap cordova app zoom

Tags: html, cordova, phonegap

After building the app for android, it looks like zoomed out. How can I solve this problem? I am using phonegap versioncli-6.5.0 and in index.html file i am using this meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

1st picture indicates what I get and 2nd picture indicates how it should be

[image]

[image]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579372/2401386) might help you.

Comment: Great! It actually worked. Thanks